# unable to use internal storage in android

Tags: android

I'm learning from treehouse and building a self destructing messaging           app [tutotrial link](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-selfdestructing-message-android-app) now the instructer is saying save files in external storage but since i don't have a device with external storage i want to save file in internal storage and i wrote this code but it seems not working

```
private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int mediaType) {
    String appName = null;
    File mediaStorage = null;
    if(isExternameStorageAvailable()){
        // 1. get the external storage directory
        appName = MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.app_name);
        mediaStorage = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), appName);
        // 2. create our subdir
        if(!mediaStorage.exists()){
            if(!mediaStorage.mkdirs()){
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // 3. create a file name
        // TODO: 05 05

        // 4. create the file
    }else{
        appName = MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.app_name);
        ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        mediaStorage = contextWrapper.getDir(appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!mediaStorage.exists()){
            if(!mediaStorage.mkdirs()){
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    File mediaFile = null;
    Date now = new Date();
    String timeStampe = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(now);
    String path = mediaStorage.getPath() + File.separator;
    if(mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(path + "IMG_" + timeStampe + ".jpg");
    }else if(mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDOE){
        mediaFile = new File(path + "VID_" + timeStampe + ".mp4");
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "FILE:" + Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
    return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
}
```

all the Uri object is returning `null`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this, I used this to access and make directory in internal storage:

```
String internalPath = Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of external storage as a sd/memory stick. It will exist on your device as a virtual folder on your device.

> All Android devices have two file storage areas: "internal" and "external" storage. These names come from the early days of Android, when most devices offered built-in non-volatile memory (internal storage), plus a removable storage medium such as a micro SD card (external storage). Some devices divide the permanent storage space into "internal" and "external" partitions, so even without a removable storage medium, there are always two storage spaces and the API behavior is the same whether the external storage is removable or not. The following lists summarize the facts about each storage space.
>   More at...
>   http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#InternalVsExternalStorage